# Return value from PHP function

Tags: php

what is wrong with the following code? Hope you understand what I'm trying to do. I'm not very familiar with functions.

```
function test ($variable) {
   $one = 3;
   if ($variable == 10) {
       $one = "2";
   }
   return $one;
}

foreach ($array as $arraypart) { 
   $part = explode(',',$arraypart);
   test($part[0]);
   echo $one;
}
```

Comment: PHP has documentation where you can learn more about functions: http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Comment: Learn about scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I am glad nobody suggested "global $one" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign the result of function to a variable:

```
$one = test($part[0]);
```

Comment: You should also point out that this `$one` is different than the `$one` in the `test` function.

Comment: Or just directly echo it... echo test($part[0]);

Answer (score 0):

here what happens, your function is being called but no variable is there to catch what test() is returning....

you need catch value which is returned by temp func like this

$val = temp($part[0]);
     or 
you can write direct echo temp($part[0]);